# Can i generate google meet link using core php

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-meet

I am working on an education website where teachers need to generate google meet link for student for 1v1 class.
The solutions I am seeing on internet is to linking google calendar etc. I am confused what to do. I just want to generate simple google meet meeting link through my website which is coded in PHP.

Comment: If the Google API offers an endpoint to create a meeting then it will be possible (in any programming language)

Comment: The [Event.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert) will create a meets link if you send conferenceData as part of the request.  Start with the quickstart then add the event insert method [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the date of this answer there is no direct API for Google Meet, meaning, there's not an option to create a Google Meet link without creating a calendar event first.

There's a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/157261118) for this very same request, where it was stated:

> "... As you are aware there is currently no Meet API, real-time or otherwise, and while this has been considered, there are no immediate plans to implement one. Therefore, implementing a direct Meet API has been deemed infeasible. This issue is going to be closed for now, however, please do continue to "star" it if you would like to see something like this implemented ..."

An alternative to this could be to create a bot that creates the Google Calendar event along with its link, grab the event link and then delete the event.